# How to allow an inline model with Foreign Key to be used only once?

Tags: django

**My Goal:**

When I add Inlines in admin, to add that Model Object, only one Inline Item with a particular Foreign Key should be allowed.

**My Models:**

```
class RateCard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=timezone.now().year)


class BillingCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Billing Categories"


class BillingCatagoryRate(models.Model):
    billing_category = models.ForeignKey(BillingCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate_card = models.ForeignKey(RateCard,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Refer the admin screenshot.**

I can select the Drop Down with same value more than once and save successfully. What I need is, RateCard should have only one BillingCatagory used once . NOT multiple (like shown in the picture)

**My Ideas:**

During Save, may be we can check if there are any duplicates in Billing Categories.

[image]

Comment: mark it `unique=True`?

Comment: @spectras....Making it OneToOneField or unique=True create anpther problem. If I create another rate card, I cannot create a BillingCatagoryRate using the Billing Category used in previous Rate Card

Comment: That's because the database server you are using is not standard-compliant. Let me guess: MS SQL?

Comment: @spectras...worse...SQL Lite (just for development) ...later on MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally solved it . I added a check in admin.py for the ModelAdmin class.

We need to override the "**save_formset**" method to access the inline values . This is how my RateCardAdmin looks.

```
class RateCardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = RateCard
    list_display = ('name', 'year')
    inlines = [BillingCatagoryRateInline]


    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        ids = []
        for data in formset.cleaned_data:
            ids.append(data['billing_category'])
        common_ids = [item for item , count in collections.Counter(ids).items() if count > 1]
        if common_ids:
            raise ValidationError('Billing Category Duplicate found')
        formset.save()
```

Comment: Beware that this has an inherent race condition: if you (or two users) save two different objects with the same billing category at the same time, there is a significant chance they will both pass the check, then both save the duplicate entry.